# How to force a stereo microphone to mono in software (W7)?

Tags: windows-7, audio, microphone, stereo, mono

I am having an issue: I have a two channel external audio card and an XLR microphone connected to the first channel, while the second channel is unconnected.

This configuration results in Windows finding a stereo audio device, but audio comes only from the left channel. I'd like to know if it is possible to fix it in software, without having to build a Y-XLR cable.

The two "solutions" I can think of are to either force the device to be registered as mono, or pan/mix the left channel to the right one. Or, if it were possible, to split the device into two "virtual devices", with one channel each.

The soundcard's driver software does not provide too much help:

[image: Sound card driver software]

Also, I can not always switch it from the application as the applications I am trying to get it to work are things like Skype, games, etc.

In applications that the audio card is "made to be used with" (DAW and other "pro"-audio work software) it is not usually a problem to fiddle with the channel however I want.

Possibly a duplicate of [this](https://superuser.com/questions/402929/can-i-make-a-stereo-microphone-output-in-mono), however other that the title, I am not currently sure about what he is asking.

Comment: If you simply need a mono mic for certain applications and quality isn't critical for those, one solution would be to just pick up a cheapie mic (you can find them for a few bucks), and use that for those applications.

Comment: @fixer1234 On that route I could also get/make a Y-cable that splits the signal for the two channels. However I thought there might have been a simple checkbox somewhere that does the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think Windows offers such a feature. You can solve this by using software that simulates virtual audio devices and cables. I use Voicemeeter (http://vb-audio.pagesperso-orange.fr/Voicemeeter/index.htm) and it works (same situation - external audio interface + XLR mic). There are some alternatives as well. Search for "windows virtual audio".

How to for Voicemeeter:
In Voicemeeter assign the XLR stereo input to an input. Toggle 'mono' button. In programs like Skype use Voicemeeter Virtual Output as input device.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Equalizer APO:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/equalizerapo/files/

After installing APO to your microphone device using the Configurator, you can use the Configuration Editor to target the microphone device for processing (by clicking the green plus button, Control -> Device).

Currently, APO doesn't have a built-in mono mixer. Instead, you could use a 64-bit VST plugin within APO. Here are some sites that provide a mono plugin:

https://www.izotope.com/en/products/downloads/ozone_imager2.html

https://www.plugin-alliance.com/en/products/bx_solo.html

These sites require you to login and license the VSTs for free. Do take note of the destination folder of the installation.

After install, you could click on the green plus button (Plugins -> VST Plugin) again to add the VST plugin to APO.

Click on [Open panel] will show the VST's interface. It may require you to authorize the plugins first before it can function. Afterwards, adjust the configuration of the VST to make the microphone sound output mono mix.

Answer (score -1):

If you can use windows native audio controls you can do the following:

1. Go to the `Control Panel` (from the `Start Menu` or `My Computer`)
2. Navigate to `Hardware and Sound -> Manage Audio Devices`
3. On the `Recording` tab, select the recording device you are using and click the `Properties` button in the lower right hand corner.
4. In the dialog that pops up, on the `Levels` tab, there should be a `Balance` button.
5. Lower the volume of the right channel to zero.

[image]

Comment: But does it copy the left channel to the right?

Comment: If you are not getting any audio from the right channel, why do you want to merge it?

Comment: Well I want to have either a stereo device with the "left mic channel" on both channels, or a mono device with from the left channel. So for example in skype or other voip programs the others hear my voice through both channels